# Looking for Flipbook frameworks. Any alternatives to Turn.js?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, page-flipping

I've been looking for some time now and can't find good alternatives to Turn.js. Turn.js seems fine, but I'd like to see some alternatives before spending the cash. If there is opensource alternatives that would be even better.

The main features I'm looking for are:

- No flash (not mandatory)
- Zoom
- Fast
- Ability to customize layout

Comment: I wish people would stop closing these types of questions. These are some of the best questions. Every time I find invaluable suggestions for frameworks and resources. I have to save screenshots of pages in fear that they will be removed. I realize you have your own idea of what the spirit of StackOverflow is but that is just not helpful.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ts1/flipbook-vue .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're okay with flash check [FlashPageFlip](http://www.flashpageflip.com/), there's a [free](http://www.flashpageflip.com/demos/free/) version available to commercial projects, it feels pretty fast and supports zoom.

There's also [WowBook](http://codecanyon.net/item/wowbook-create-ebooks-with-page-flip/full_screen_preview/1791563) a paid jQuery plugin that's pretty nice.

Comment: Obrigado for the suggestions. I'm gonna look into them! I forgot to mention "bookmarkers" as a feature I'm also looking for. FlashPageFlip seems to support it, but it would be great to have them on screen at all times. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You're weclome, I don't think wowBook has a bookmarkers option, but it allows anchor linking to a specific page of the "book" so you could somewhat easily implement a bookmarkers view (example: http://3.s3.envato.com/files/53574557/index.html#features/5)

Comment: Thumbs up for wowbook, the performance is way better on mobile than turn-js's.

Comment: Here's framework to develop and publish responsive books on the web: http://bookiza.io